# Friends of friends in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a self-referrential association `Friendship`. A user has many friends through friendships. I want to get a list of friends of friends. What would be the most efficient way to do this? I'm using ActiveRecord. Thanks!

Comment: You should include at least *some* attempt at resolving the problem in your question. SO is not a forum to request others write your code for you.

Comment: @eirikir If you haven't noticed, this is not a request for others to write some code for me. Please read the question carefully: I'm not asking for a solution, but for some ideas on how to improve efficiency. SO is also not a forum to write pointless comments without constructive content. I would love to see your ideas on this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ignore him @dan, that was a perfectly reasonable question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through => :friendships, :class_name => "User"

  def friends_of_friends
    User.joins(:friendships).where(:user_id => friendships.pluck(:friend_id))
  end

end
```

The friendship model would be something like

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'

end
```

Comment: What is `Friend` in this context?

Comment: `friends` is an association in the User class that returns an array of user objects.  The `friend` in friendship is just an alias. It has the affect of using the `friend_id` as the foreign key - again, returning a user object.